# Does readlines() return a list or an iterator in Python 3?

Tags: python, iterator, python-3.x, readlines

I've read in "Dive into Python 3" that:

> *"The `readlines()` method now returns an iterator, so it is just as efficient as `xreadlines()` was in Python 2".*

See: [Appendix A: Porting Code to Python 3 with 2to3: A.26 xreadlines() I/O method](https://diveintopython3.problemsolving.io/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#xreadlines).

I'm not sure that's true because they don't mention it here: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html . How can I check that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like this:

```
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79149, Mar 21 2010, 00:41:52) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open('/junk/so/foo.txt')
>>> type(f.readlines())
<class 'list'>
>>> help(f.readlines)
Help on built-in function readlines:

readlines(...)
    Return a list of lines from the stream.

    hint can be specified to control the number of lines read: no more
    lines will be read if the total size (in bytes/characters) of all
    lines so far exceeds hint.

>>>
```

Answer (score 44):

The readlines method doesn't return an iterator in Python 3, it returns a list

```
Help on built-in function readlines:

readlines(...)
    Return a list of lines from the stream.
```

To check, just call it from an interactive session - it will return a list, rather than an iterator:

```
>>> type(f.readlines())
<class 'list'>
```

Dive into Python appears to be wrong in this case.

---

`xreadlines` has been [deprecated since Python 2.3](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/highlights/) when file objects became their own iterators. The way to get the same efficiency as `xreadlines` is instead of using

```
 for line in f.xreadlines():
```

[you should use simply](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-xreadlines)

```
 for line in f:
```

This gets you the iterator that you want, and helps to explain why `readlines` didn't need to change its behaviour in Python 3 - it can still return a full list, with the `line in f` idiom giving the iterative approach, and the long-deprecated `xreadlines` has been removed completely.

Comment: I would expect that anybody who was using `for line in f.xreadlines():` will have converted it to `for line in f:` years ago.

Comment: @John Machin: I'd hope so too (though perhaps not expect it!) I didn't mean to imply that `xreadlines` was the preferred way to do it in Python 2 - it was deprecated way back in Python 2.3 when the file-as-iterator method was introduced. I just meant to give the reason it could be removed in Python 3.

Comment: I only discovered files were their own iterators about a week ago :( I guess that serves me right for not looking at the tutorial/release notes since 1.5.

Comment: This answer is better because it also provides the answer to the implicit question: how do you get an iterator on files?

Answer (score 7):

Others have said as much already, but just to drive the point home, ordinary file objects are their own iterators. So having `readlines()` return an iterator would be silly, because it would just return the file you called it on. You can use a `for` loop to iterate over a file, like Scott said, and you can also pass them straight to itertools functions:

```
from itertools import islice
f = open('myfile.txt')
oddlines = islice(f, 0, None, 2)
firstfiveodd = islice(oddlines, 5)
for line in firstfiveodd:
  print(line)
```

Comment: Not entirely silly, because the `hint` argument of `readlines` (which stops reading new lines after `hint` chars/bytes have been read) can be useful when working with very large files. And that is also exactly when you want an iterator rather than a list.