# Read lines from txt python

Tags: python, text, lines

I am having a txt file and I want to read its lines in python. Basically I am using the following method:

```
f = open(description,'r')
out = f.readlines() 

for line in out:
    line
```

What I want is to have access in every line of the text after the for loop. Thus, to store lines in a matrix or something list-like.

Comment: You are right, thanks, new to python. Now, if I want to have access to line elements, I ve got to use something like split element?

Comment: By "line elements" do you mean each entire line? Or individual characters on each line?

Comment: I ve got numbers which they split with spaces.

Comment: Yeah, you can do `out = list(l.strip().split(" ") for l in f)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of readlines you could use

```
lines = list(open(description, 'r'))
```

The opened file is an iterator, that yields lines. By calling `list` on it, you create a list of all of them. There's no real need to keep the open file around in a variable, doing it this way it will be closed.

But using readlines() to get a list is perfectly good as well.

Comment: `readlines()` already creates a list. (Even in Python 3, despite your comment on the deleted answer).

Comment: Crap, sorry. I did a quick Googling before that comment, and read that Dive into Python 3 mentions it's an iterator now -- but didn't read on, the answers to that question explain that it doesn't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541203/does-readlines-return-a-list-or-an-iterator-in-python-3

Comment: Ah. Dive Into Python is notoriously inaccurate in places.