# Python file.readline(2) reads first 2 charectars

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am new to Python, and you might have seen the question I asked earlier about a similar issue.  I tried to run the code below, but it just prints the first to letters of the first line (Us).  It is probably my own beginner's stupidity, but I would really appreciate some help with the issue.  Thank you in advance if you can solve my issue!

Code I tried to run below:

```
file = open("createdFile.txt", "w")
file.write("User Data Number:\n")
file.write("10101")
file.close()
file = open("createdFile.txt", "r")
getUserNumber = file.readline(2)
print(getUserNumber)
file.close()
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code....?

Comment: `readline(2)` doesn't mean "read line 2". It means "read up to 2 characters of a line".

Comment: Passing a number to `readline()` limits it to reading that number of bytes.  Did you even try to read the documentation?

Comment: @user2357112 Okay, then how would you read a certain line of the text doc?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, it shows that I am doing the correct thing, maybe I misread something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getUserNumber = file.readlines()[1]` instead.

`readline` reads the next line, and the arg is how many characters to read, so previously you were reading the first two characters of the first line.

So instead what you should do to accomplish what you want is to read all the lines (`file.readlines()`), and then pick out the line you want (`[1]`).

Comment: One question, this only lets me read 1 line, than it shows its out of range in an error message, do you know what this could be?

Comment: however I would recommend against that when working with big files -- with `readlines()` you get a **list** of all lines (not iterator, [see here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541203/does-readlines-return-a-list-or-an-iterator-in-python-3)), so be careful if you only need the second line of big file, you can simply `readline()` twice

Comment: @EP what if I have a file with 4 lines, and I want to get the 2 and 4, then what would you suggest doing?

Comment: @houbysoft I tried using your method, but that still gave the same "out of range" error message.  I typed, lines = file.readlines(), then I typed  variable = lines[2].  Is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: @profound.donut what does `print(len(lines))` say after you do `lines = file.readlines()` ?

Comment: @EP I get the same error (IndexError: list index out of range)

Comment: @houbysoft Yes.  By the way, thank you so much for trying to help me out with this.

Comment: @profound.donut  but seriously -- what does the following code produce? `with open("createdFile.txt", "r") as f: lines = f.readlines(); print(len(lines))`